# How can I inline database access code?

Tags: asp.net, database, inline

I have an aspx page, from where I want to give if condition. I have a parameterized function in app_code, which returns a value. I want to check values for blank, if the value is blank, it should execute the else block. This function I want to call under gridview ItemTemplate. and the parameter is the database field "ID" value.

In other words, here is what I want to do..

```
if functionName(parameter is databaseField Value) Then
    functionName(parameter is databaseField Value)
End If
```

Here is what I am doing.

```
<% If customTransactions.GetAuthorToBlogEntry(
    CType(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"EntryID"), Integer)) <> "" %>
    by 
<% End If %>
```

Can anyone suggest how to call my database field in this way?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear.  Can you provide more information?  Maybe show some code of what you've already tried?

Comment: @Alison: i want to use inline code in aspx page, want to call the parameterised function, whose parameter value will be database field. i want to call this function under gridview's ItemTemplate, above i have specified what i tried..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this is what you ask
You call the function this way

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Header Title" >
   <ItemTemplate ><%#GetYourData(Container.DataItem)%></ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

and the code behind.

```
protected string GetYourData(object oItem)
{
   // here is the way you get the data on code behind
   return DataBinder.Eval(oItem, "EntryID").ToString();
}
```